# How do I properly save Json from website that gives results as Json dictionary?

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Json and Python.
I get results from website as

```
{"urlkey": "se,009)/", "url": "https://009.se/"}
{"urlkey": "se,013159560)/", "url": "http://013159560.se/"}
{"urlkey": "se,013159560,blogg)/", "url": "http://blogg.013159560.se/"}
{"urlkey": "se,018maleri)/", "url": "https://018maleri.se/"}
```

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

html_text = requests.get("https://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2021-21-index?url=*.se&output=json&filter=languages:swe&fl=urlkey,url&filter=~urlkey:se,(.*)\)\/$&pageSize=10").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
results = soup.find('p').text
j = json.dumps(results, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
with open('Results.json', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(j)
    f.close()
```

But every new line get saved as "\n" and before every " there is a backslash like: \ " (without the space in between).
Did I save it right?
And how do I extract every "url" from that file?

Edit:
Json file that I save everything to looks like this:

```
"{\"urlkey\": \"se,009)/\", \"url\": \"https://009.se/\"}\n{\"urlkey\": \"se,013159560)/\", \"url\": \"http://013159560.se/\"}\n{\"urlkey\": \"se,013159560,blogg)/\", \"url\": \"http://blogg.013159560.se/\"}\n{\"urlkey\": \"se,018maleri)/\", \"url\": \"https://018maleri.se/\"}\n{\"urlkey\": \"se,018radio)/\", \"url\": \"https://018radio.se/\"}\n{\"urlkey\": \"se,021grappling)/\", \"url\": \"http://021grappling.se/\"}\n{\"urlkey\": \"se,021media)/\", \"url\": \"https://www.021media.se/\"}\n{\"urlkey\": \"se,031flytt)/\", \"url\": \"https://www.031flytt.se/\"}\n{\"urlkey\": \"se,035gruppen)/\", \"url\": \"https://www.035gruppen.se/\"}\n{\"urlkey\": \"se,035hemtjanst)/\", \"url\": \"http://035hemtjanst.se/\"}\n{\"urlkey\": \"se,036100200)/\", \"url\": \"http://www.036100200
```

(Everything is just cramped and hard to read. I don't even know if I'll be able to extract anything from that?)

Comment: Looks like `results` is already `JSON`, no need to convert it to JSON again

Comment: @mousetail you mean j = json.dumps(results, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')?

Comment: Yea, if you look at `results` you will see it is already JSON encoded

Comment: So I can just delete that line? (Sorry if its a dumb question)

Comment: Yes, you can delete the whole BeautifulSoup part too since it's not HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your code is not needed, it can be reduced to this:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2021-21-index?url=*.se&output=json&filter=languages:swe&fl=urlkey,url&filter=~urlkey:se,(.*)\)\/$&pageSize=10")
response.raise_for_status() # Make sure there are no http errors
with open("results.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

Comment: a quick question, if I then want to import just link from that file, whats the best way to do so?

Comment: You can parse the JSON, modify it, then convert the result back to JSON. If you need more help consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import requests

html_text = requests.get("https://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2021-21-index?url=*.se&output=json&filter=languages:swe&fl=urlkey,url&filter=~urlkey:se,(.*)\)\/$&pageSize=10").text

with open('Results.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_text)
```

Results.json:

```
{"urlkey": "se,009)/", "url": "https://009.se/"}
{"urlkey": "se,013159560)/", "url": "http://013159560.se/"}
{"urlkey": "se,013159560,blogg)/", "url": "http://blogg.013159560.se/"}
{"urlkey": "se,018maleri)/", "url": "https://018maleri.se/"}
.
.
.
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please provide an example of the file structure you want.